# Cross-origin request blocked--app built with Angular and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I'm building a web site with Angular and ASP.NET Core.

On some pages I want to get data from a Web API. When I run the app, the browser (Firefox) shows that

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ...(the url) (Reason: missing token ‘authorization’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

I tried other browsers, got the same error.

For authorization consideration, I use a `HttpInterceptor` to insert an authorization header for each request from Angular frontend.

Then I looked into my ASP.NET Core backend. I set the CORS policy as            `app.UseCors(builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); });`, but it still doesn't work.

I tested the API with Postman, it works fine.

Where's going wrong?

The `Startup.cs` file.

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(
            opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            );

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddSignalR();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Remote"));
        });

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(opts =>
        {
            opts.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            opts.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            opts.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opts.Password.RequiredLength = 7;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
        {
            opts.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Auth:Jwt:Key"])),
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidateAudience = true
            };
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("NonUser", policy => policy.RequireRole("RestrauntOwner", "RestrauntAdmin", "SystemAdmin"));
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
        app.UseCors(builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); });
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseSignalR(route =>
        {
            route.MapHub<OrderHub>("/orderhub");
        });
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It's weird. I heve been developing this on my Windows PC for some time. I cloned the project on my MacBook, it worked fine without any problems on macOS.

Comment: make sure `app.UseMvc()` is at the last. Share your `ConfigureServices` code

Answer (score 4):

If you can't quite get it working here's a couple tips:

#### Your origin must match EXACTLY with what the browser is sending.

- If it's HTTP you must put HTTP, and HTTPS must be HTTPS.
- Port number must be included too and correct.

> http://localhost:5000

> https://localhost:5001

- So don't put a CORS rule for `"http://localhost:5001"` if you're using the above settings because that isn't the same URL!
- Look in the browser, or Fiddler to get it exactly right and make sure it is what you expect. If switching between HTTP and HTTPS it's very easy to get confused.

[image]

#### You will get a 204 with an empty response if what you send doesn't match

- It's not going to reveal to you the correct data it is expecting if you get it wrong

#### Headers are NOT case sensitive

- You can put `"authorization"` or `"Authorization"` or `"aUtHoRiZaTiOn"` if you want.

#### You MUST include methods as well as headers

- If you don't specify the allowed HTTP methods using `WithMethods` or `AllowAnyMethod` it won't work. This is very easy to miss - especially for just a GET request.

#### If using middleware or a branched MVC pipeline you can add CORS at that level.

For `app.UseSpa` (if you're using Microsoft's hosting mechanism for SPA) you can do this

```cs
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    // CORS just for the SPA
    spa.ApplicationBuilder.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        // Must specify Methods
        builder.WithMethods("GET");

        // Case insensitive headers
        builder.WithHeaders("AuthoriZatioN");

        // Can supply a list or one by one, either is fine
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:5000");
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:5001");
    });
}
```

#### Fiddler is useful

Fiddler will show you the required conditions for CORS to succeed. Here it is `authorization` header and `GET` method.

You can hit `R` on a previous request to rerun it after changing server configuration. That way you don't have to keep firing up your browser.

Make sure to look at `Headers` in the response section because the actual content will be 0 bytes even when successful.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Reason behind this error is  : Your client project and webapi are on different domain( or port ).

> Browser security prevents a web page from making AJAX requests to another domain. This restriction is called the same-origin policy, and prevents a malicious site from reading sensitive data from another site.

To set up CORS for your application add the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors** package to your project.

Then Enabling CORS with middleware : in startup > ConfigureServices method

```cs
//For any origin
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
            builder1 => builder1.WithOrigins("http://web.user.local:44352"));
    });
}
```

And in Configure method  :

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{          
    // Shows UseCors with named policy.
    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

    //...rest
}
```

> Note: The URL must be specified without a trailing slash (/). If the URL terminates with /, the comparison will return false and no header will be returned.

For more info [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: As you can see in my description, I set up CORS with `app.UseCors(builder => { builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader(); });`. And even I do it like what you wrote above, it doesn't work either. I posted my `Startup.cs` file, hope that you might check if there's anything wrong.

Comment: @PhoenixFeng, in **ConfigurationService**, you have added only **services.AddCors();**,  review updated answer, and compare it once. let me know if you still face issue

Comment: I've tried that. ` services.AddCors(opt => {
                opt.AddPolicy("AllowAny", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                });
            });` Then I use the AllowAny policy. It's still the same error.

Comment: are you doing all this in webapi project's startup.cs file, right ?
I just tested my code and it is working.

for once, try exactly  what i did in answer.

Comment: Of course I did all this in the Startup.cs file. I did try what you did. Sadly, it doesn't work for me. I checked the log in the ASP.NET Core server output window, there was something weird. The log said Policy execution successful, but the browser kept complaining Cross-origin requests was blocked. Thus I doubt that maybe something else causes the problem?

Comment: I found something even more weird. I don’t know if there’s something wrong with the latest update of Windows. I cloned the project on my MacBook and it ran without any errors on macOS. I even browsed it on the same browser.

Comment: That was happen many times with me too, sometimes we need some air and when we come back to workspace, everything started working again.... anyways cheers....:)

Comment: Thanks anyway. I will post the solution when I found what's wrong with this.

Comment: @PhoenixFeng, did you crack the case?

Answer (score 2):

OK. I found what't wrong, it's kinda silly though.

I asked the web API provider. He told me that it was because the authorization header wasn't allowed.

I use a `HttpIntercepter` to insert a authorization header into every request fired form Angular frontend. I did this to let my ASP.NET Core Web API to authenticate the users of the site. But the open web API doesn't allow this header.

It works if I didn't log in on my website, but if I do perform the login procedure, it will get a token and insert an authorization into the request, and it will fire a OPTIONS preflight request, well, then the request will be blocked.

Such a silly question :) I gotta find a new way to do this.